# PoE+ Hat, fan not spinning until level 3

Tags: hat, poe

I’m not sure if it’s a problem or not, but here is what’s happening:

The fan on the PoE hat only starts spinning at level 3, and louder at level 4. On level 1 and 2, the fan it’s spinning at all. It’s also producing a noticeable whistling when it starts spinning (so 3 for me).

Here are my /boot/config.txt params for the fan:

```
dtparam=poe_fan_temp0=55000
dtparam=poe_fan_temp0_hyst=5000
dtparam=poe_fan_temp1=60000
dtparam=poe_fan_temp1_hyst=5000
dtparam=poe_fan_temp2=65000
dtparam=poe_fan_temp2_hyst=5000
dtparam=poe_fan_temp3=75000
dtparam=poe_fan_temp3_hyst=5000
```

For example, currently typing `sensors` give me a temp of 62°C. Then to see the current level of the fan I do `cat /sys/class/thermal/cooling_device0/cur_state`, and it outputs `2` - but the fan isn't spinning!

Is it the expected behavior?

Hardware specs:

- Raspberry Pi 4B 8GB
- PoE+ Hat
- 240GB SSD w/ USB 3.0 adapter

Software specs:

- Raspberry OS Lite 64bit (also tested on Ubuntu Server 21 64bit, same issue)

Comment: since 64bit is not production ready, have you tried 32bit - I doubt it'll be different, but worth a shot

Comment: Which PoE Hat are you using? Maybe the voltage levels for the lower speeds are just to low, so that the fan doesn't start turning.

Comment: I’m using the latest official PoE+ Hat. Gonna try with 32bits